add a customized module inside cuckoo sandbox
I'm trying to add a custom processing module to Cuckoo Sandbox for my analysis tasks, but I'm encountering some difficulties in getting it to work properly. I've followed the documentation and made sure that my module is correctly structured and enabled in the configuration file (cuckoo.conf). However, when I run Cuckoo Sandbox, it seems that my custom module is not being recognized or executed.
Here are the steps I've taken:
Created a custom processing module called simple_module.py.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from cuckoo.common.abstracts import Processing

class SimpleModule(Processing):
    def __init__(self):
        Processing.__init__(self)
    def run(self, results):
        self.key = "simple_info"
        data = "This is the data returned by simple_module."
        self.mark_config(data)
        self.completed()

Placed the module in the appropriate directory (cuckoo/processing/) within the Cuckoo Sandbox directory.
Enabled the module in the cuckoo.conf file under the [simple_module] section and ensured that enabled = yes.
Restarted Cuckoo Sandbox to apply the changes.
Despite these steps, when I run an analysis task, I see in the logs that my module is not found or executed.
DEBUG: Processing module simple_module not found in configuration file
Can anyone provide guidance on what might be causing this issue? Are there additional steps I need to take to ensure that my custom processing module is properly configured and executed by Cuckoo Sandbox?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
whene i run cuckoo sandbox its run normaly without any probeleme
and in the logs i see the error message:
DEBUG: Processing module simple_module not found in configuration file
